# Remove ".000000" from a field like this: "2386.000000"

Tags: sql, databricks

How do I remove the ".000000" part of the "2386.000000" field? I want to leave only the numerical part before the dot in databricks

Comment: The "2386.000000" field? Is this about a column? If so, what data type is this? Are you storing the value as a string? Then use a string function to remove the dot and the zeros. Are you storing this as a number? Then this is just the way the number gets displayed. Change that in the app that displays the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cast](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/cast.html)

```
select cast(2386.000000 as int) i
```

Comment: I up-ticked this answer since it is one way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to convert a float to an int.  The cast() function is just one.

Please see the following link for all supported Spark SQL functions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#round

In my solution, I use the round() function.  As long as you get the correct answer, the path you take may differ.

[image]